# NHibernate + ActiveRecord + PostgreSQL = memoryexception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, postgresql, activerecord, castle-activerecord

I have a system in winforms C#.Net 2.0 with ActiveRecord + NHibernate communicating with a PostgreSQL 9 database.
When user open the system, starts the communication with the DB by a new SessionScope(). For some users it works perfectly... but for others the system generates a memoryexception, identical to the problem of Marcio in msdn forum: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt/wcfpt/thread/d7ac4540-46cd-4512-b4c9-eff400538152?prof=required). 
How can I solve this problem? The problem is in NHibernate! The error occurs when I try to close the ISession object or when I try to Commit the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

An underlying reason for OutOfMemoryException can be outside of the code that you posted. You simply have a memory leak and it can be anywhere in your app. The exception will be thrown from the code that tries to allocate more memory, not necessarily from the code that causes memory leak. Use memory [profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) to figure out what causes the memory leak.

It is very likely however that this issue is due to bloated 1st level cache in NHibernate. From [SessionScope](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/manual/scopes.html) document:

> At the same time, NHibernate is keeping tracks of changes to objects
>   within the scope. If there are too many objects and too many changes
>   to keep track, then performance will slowly downgrade. So a flushing
>   now and then will be required.

- Get rid of GC calls, you don't need them.
- Limit the scope of the session
- Flush/Clear session periodically
- Make sure that you use [lazy loading](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/v1rc1/usersguide/lazy.html) appropriately (don't load information you don't need from database)

Comment: Oh...thanks for your answer. But... I've a login method that always works for some users and always fails to others. The error is NOT random! It's always occur when NHibernate tries to commit the transaction!!!

I've included the GC calls on my code to try to solve the problem, they are not standards of my source code.
There aren't many objects in the scope of NHibernate, because the application is just beginning. The error is in function login()!

Comment: And:
Yes! I'm cleaning up the session regularly! I've a protected  function CloseSession() that does this!
Yes! I'm using the "lazy" correctly! No load information I don't need! I have many "Lazy = true" in my code!
I think this is an internal bug of NHibernate... Marcio (msdn, link on top) has the same problem! What do you think about that?

I'm brazilian... Sorry for my bad english! ;)

Comment: The bug in NHibernate is possible but very unlikely. You may have memory leak somewhere in your app. Maybe you holding on to objects longer than needed and GC is unable to clear them up. Use the memory profiler that I mention in my answer, they have free trial.

Comment: Yes, I did it! I started the application, marked memory and saved the snapshot. I don't understand very well dotTrace, but the snapshot is available for you look: http://www.4shared.com/file/R2sd6Hgt/error.html

Comment: Alright... I did it! Thanks for example!  See the result: In snapshots of my problem appears to 99.76% of memory on NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(). 49.88% on NHibernate.Loader.InitializeEntitiesAndCollections() -> NHibernate.Type.MutableType.DeepCopy() and 49.88% NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRowFromResultSet () -> NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRow() -> InstanceNotYetLoaded() -> LoadFromResultSet()  -> NHibernate.Type.AbstractBinaryType.Get()

Comment: The problem occurs into the .dll of NHibernate. I have no control over these methods! None memory leaks occur within the namespace of my own application! And now? Becomes a little more likely an error in Hibernate?

Comment: I really doubt that it is nhibernate. It also seems like you were looking at performance, not memory profiler.

Comment: I did exactly as example!! Why not look by yourself? Pleaseeeeeeeeee! http://www.4shared.com/file/flAv5W6c/error.html

Comment: Hey you! I'm using the dotTrace 3.5 Memory not dotTrace 4.5 Performance... I installed only Memory! See there ... and make sure that I did everything right! You think I did wrong, but I didn't! I'm professional too. Download the Snapshots (2.648 KB) and see by yourself! Please!

Comment: Dear professional. Looks like you are loading to much information for certain users. Hibernate is not broken. You have enough information in the answer to proceed on your own. Feel free to ask more _specific_ questions. But please "avoid extended discussions in comments."